# Using ExecutorService but stopping after submitted tasks executed

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

## Executor not stopping even completed executing tasks

```
    Here am calling awaitTermination to wait until all executing tasks to be completed here the problem is, it's not terminating executor service for a long time, once stopping server then only getting InterruptedException otherwise it's waiting until unless we are stopping the server, not sure what am missing here, is this reason  Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS its not terminates even completed submitted tasks? Thanks.

<pre><code>
      executorService.shutdown();
      try {
        executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
</code></pre>
```

Comment: What tasks have you submitted to the executor service?  They are evidently taking a long time.  Can you compile a [mre] that is **separate** from your actual project, and then add it to your question?

Comment: This is my entire code, I posted as answer

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide enough detail nail down your problem. So here is a complete example of working code similar to yours.

Tip: Get your code working as plain Java before embedding in a [JSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Server_Pages).

## Conventional syntax

First we use the conventional syntax of today's Java.

Key part of the code:

```java
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 7 ; i++ )
        {
            executorService.submit( new PrintUuid() );
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        try { executorService.awaitTermination( Long.MAX_VALUE , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

An entire example app.

```java
package work.basil.example.simple;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "INFO - End of `demo` method. " + Instant.now() );

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 7 ; i++ )
        {
            executorService.submit( new PrintUuid() );
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        try { executorService.awaitTermination( Long.MAX_VALUE , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        System.out.println( "INFO - End of `demo` method. " + Instant.now() );
    }

    class PrintUuid implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run ( )
        {
            try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 2 ).toMillis() ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
            System.out.println( "uuid = " + uuid + " at " + Instant.now() + " by thread ID # " + Thread.currentThread().getId() );
        }
    }
}
```

As part of your debugging, get that code exactly as written to work within your app. Then transition to your actual task to run concurrently. After that is all working, move code into your JSP.

## Project Loom

[*Project Loom*](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main) will bring innovations in the concurrency facilities of Java. Experimental builds based on early-access Java 17 are [available now](http://jdk.java.net/loom/).

One of the changes being considered is to make [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) interface [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html). This means we can use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax. The flow-of-control passes the `try` block only after all submitted tasks are done.

A smaller change is support for *java.time* classes. This includes using [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) as alternative to an `int` count of milliseconds when sleeping the current thread.

```java
package work.basil.example.simple;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "INFO - End of `demo` method. " + Instant.now() );

        try (
                ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() ;
        )
        {
            for ( int i = 0 ; i < 7 ; i++ )
            {
                executorService.submit( new PrintUuid() );
            }
        }
        // At this point, flow-of-control blocks until all submitted tasks are done/canceled/failed.
        // After this point, the executor service will have been automatically shutdown, wia `close` method called by try-with-resources syntax.

        System.out.println( "INFO - End of `demo` method. " + Instant.now() );
    }

    class PrintUuid implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run ( )
        {
            try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 2 ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
            System.out.println( "uuid = " + uuid + " at " + Instant.now() + " by thread ID # " + Thread.currentThread().getId() );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: his is my entire code, I posted as another answer

Answer (score 0):

This is my total code

```
public void processActivityDeposits(
    Activity activity) {
  int partitionSize =
      environment.getProperty("patition.size", Integer.class, 1000);
  List<Long> records =
      service.findReadyToProcessRecords(
          activity.getActivityId(),
          partitionSize);
  if (records != null && records.size() > 0) {
    try {
      int threadPoolSize =
          environment.getProperty("thread.pool.size", Integer.class, 10);
      ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize);
      for (Long activityId : records) {
        executorService.execute(
            new ActivityDepositInternalProcessor(
                activityId));
      }
      executorService.shutdown();
      try {
        executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      processActivityDeposits(
          activity);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
      exception.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```